# How to test hard drive - diskutility reports defective drive as perfectly fine

Tags: hard-drive, usb, disk-utility

**long story**
I have an USB drive to copy data between Mac, Windows (personally I don't own any) and PS4 - it is exfat formatted.  Recently I noticed my Mac would freeze when I plug in this disc - also there is a directory in the top hierarchy that I could not open.  Since this drive moves around a lot I suspected an unlucky disconnection caused corruption. Checked the drive and the only partition with disk-utility "first aid" - which report everything is fine.  Despite this in the system log there are plenty of I/O errors.  Looks like I need to trash it.  But I sure had loved it if my mac gave me any warning that I was using a bad drive (I kinda forgive the PS4 that she didn't warn).

So for the future what check should I use?

I see that there are older questions discussing a similar questions, though they are 5 years old and also some of the link tools are dead now.  Also this question is not about data recovery, but how to asses a drive.

**tl;dr** What program (on mac) can I trust to check my discs?

Comment: You might want to consider purchasing an external SSD for the inevitable replacement drive instead of spinning platters, which are so 20th century.

Comment: If you have I/O errors for that drive in the system.log then you already have your answer, the drive is defective. Replace it! Disk Utility does not perform a full disk low level sector-by-sector test and that's why it can say a disk is okay when in fact it's not. You can use `dd`, which is already installed, to preform a low level sector-by-sector test.

Comment: @user3439894 I totally agree.  My confusion is just - Finder won't alert me, diskutil tells me all is ok.  In the future - how can I find out I am working on a "dying" disk?  Hoping messages in system log will pop up doesn't sound reliable to me.  Other OSes at least give some error message.

Answer (score 3):

I reccomend [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/).  Their diagnostic and monitoring tools are free, but the recovery functionality (if you need it) is what you will have to purchase.

There's also a very robust set of command line (CLI) tools available as open source:  [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download).  This is a available as a macOS binary package so you don't need to install via `brew` or `MacPorts`.

**Important:**  One thing to keep in mind when diagnosing external drives is that you have two components:

- the drive itself
- the USB enclosure

I have had USB enclosure's fail (the USB to SATA portion) that looked like a drive failure.  The best way to get around this is to remove the drive (if you can) and use a separate [USB-SATA Adapter](http://radnex.us/USB-30-SATA-Adapter).  What you are doing is eliminating one of the components from the diagnostic equation (the USB interface) with a "known working" component.  They are cheap (approx $10) to keep for diagnostic purposes.

[image]

That said, a drive diagnostic is not a "quick status check."  To find bad blocks you may need to do a "deep scan" because a bad block isn't reported until the drive encounters a bad block.

Comment: I just tested Disk Drill - it seems only to look for deleted files.  I couldn't see any indication of bad blocks or a bad drive.

Comment: I added some relevant info to the answer..

Comment: Smartmontools looks promising.  Took me some time till I found the kernel driver. And now it will run overnight with a selftest.