# See/read Mac mini hard drive from MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, mac-mini, file-transfer

My Mac mini crashed during an OS upgrade and my display simply looks a bit like my opening screen but is refreshing (jumping around?) rapidly with no way to make any keyboard input.  I'd rather not do a reset as I have some   files I want to keep.

Is there a way I can use my MacBook Air via USB or any other method to access/transfer the files so that I might retain them?

Comment: The only way to get access like you describe is [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462) the caveat being you must be able to *boot* the target computer (which it seems like it's not).  Give it a shot.  If you can't get that to work, you may want to extract the drive, use a [USB to SATA adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283022/119271) and try some recovery software.

Answer (score 1):

Allan’s response makes sense to me. I have been pretty successful retrieving files from Mac Minis using a USB to SATA adaptor. I use a Newer Technology USB 3.0 Universal Drive Adapter https://www.newertech.com/storage/

For guides to extracting the drive from the Mini, I rely on iFixIt. https://www.ifixit.com/Search?query=Mac+mini+drive

Denny

Answer (score 0):

Target disc mode is the most convenient way and this does not rely on OS thus will work even if OS is damaged.

https://support.apple.com/HT201462