# Is my SSD fried or did I screw something up when attempting to wipe and reinstall OS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, disk-utility, ssd

I’m stuck and need suggestions about what’s wrong. 2011 MacBook Pro 8,2 >Replaced HDD with SSD in Feb 2018.

It started yesterday when I was unable to login to computer user account after low battery shutdown and was unable to login via known password from either user. I noticed a new user account had been setup with name formatted like recovery key.

I tried to reset password via Terminal and it wouldn’t accept password from either user and got message that iCloud had not been setup (although it definitely had). I ran Apple Hardware Test and found no errors. So I decided to just erase SSD and reinstall macOS using Command-R.

Erased SSD volume via Disk Utility and then completed successful OS Reinstall of High Sierra. Setup new user account and opted to use FileVault with iCloud recovery but not iCloud backup. Selected option to restart and install updates via App Store when prompted. Installed updates and restarted a time or two.

Logged in under new username and got stuck at gray prohibitory screen. Restarted laptop again and went into Command-R recovery mode using Internet Recovery. Used Disk Utility and verified SSD volume was ok. Repaired via Disk Utility for good measure.

Restarted again in normal mode and got stuck at gray blank screen, before user login screen appeared. Restarted again in Command-R recovery mode using Internet Recovery.  Again verified and repaired SSD in Disk Utility.  Noticed no boot drive listed under Show All Devices.

Attempted to erase SSD in Disk Utility to install again without FileVault encryption and got a disk object invalid or unable to serialize error. Attempted to repair, but option was grayed out. Selected Show All Devices option and SSD disappeared from view.

Opened Terminal and ran diskutil list and was unable to find SSD (disk0 was not listed). Back to Disk Utility and still nothing available, so restarted again under Command-R recovery mode.
Different MacOS Utilities window opened, with same options except older (Reinstall option was for Lion, not High Sierra). SSD still not showing up under Disk Utility or Terminal list command.
Restarted again to same MacOS Utilities window and Disk Utility showed SSD.  No option to verify or repair volume. Terminal list showed SSD (as /dev/disk0). Attempted to use Terminal to verify disk0s2 (s1 was EFI), but got error starting file system verification for disk0 unrecognized file system (-69846).

Tried to use Terminal to unmount and re-mount the disk before attempting another verification and repair with diskutil eject /dev/disk0 and got an error that the command timed out. Tried again and got an error that it was unable to find disk.  Terminal diskutil list then also failed to show disk0.

Restarted again to Option-Command-R and successfully started up from Internet Recovery. Still no SSD listed – only shows OS X Base System (Disk Image Volume as device disk0s1).

Back to Terminal, `diskutil` list, shows:

```
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name                      Size        Identifier
0:GUID_partition_scheme      +2.1 GB    disk0
1:Apple_HFS OS X Base System 2.0 GB disk0s1
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +5.2 MB          disk1
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk2
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk3
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk4
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +2.1 MB          disk5
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk6
```

...through disk18

Restarted again to Option-Command-R and successfully started up from Internet Recovery.

Disk Utility shows Not Mounted 1TB capacity AFPS Volume with SATA connection named disk2s1 that is encrypted, can be verified and repaired not writeable and S.M.A.R.T. status is not supported.

Terminal `diskutil` list now shows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:    Type   Name                      Size        Identifier
0:GUID_partition_scheme   *1.0 TB        disk0
1: EFI      EFI                            209.7 MB  disk0s1
2:Apple_AFPS Container disk2 1000.0 GB disk0s2
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
#: Type   Name                       Size      Identifier
0: GUID_partition_scheme  +2.1 GB  disk1
1:  Apple_HFS  OS X Base System 2.0 GB disk1s1
/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
#: Type   Name                       Size      Identifier
0: AFPS Container Scheme - +1000.0 TB  disk2
                Physical Store
1:  APFS Volume   Feb 2018 SSD 11.4 GB disk2s1
2: APFS Volume    Preboot          46.1 MB disk2s2
3: APFS Volume    Recovery         1.0 GB. disk2s3
4: APFS Volume    VM                  4.3 GB   disk2s4
/dev/disk3 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +5.2 MB       disk3
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk4
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk5
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk6
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +2.1 MB        disk7
/dev/disk8 (disk image):
#:    Type   Name         Size                Identifier
0:                untitled     +524.3 MB     disk8
```

…through disk20

Any ideas?

Comment: The biggest issue here is too much of jumping to conclusions of what the problem is and not enough diagnosis. Before wiping the drive, at a minimum, you should at least boot verbose to see what the messages are that’s being generated. The next thing you should do is try to boot a clean environment like off of a USB drive to remove the SATA controller and drive from the equation

Comment: There’s a good chance that the SATA cable is bad - these models are notorious for this.  Check this by booting from USB. You can use the Internal drive and a [USB to SATA adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283022/119271). Also see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389422/119271) for a very similar situation.

Comment: Yeah, hindsight is 20/20 regarding the decision to wipe it and start over so quickly. (I was really just hoping to be back up and running ASAP because I have backups of almost all of my content and need the computer for some school work.)

As far as using the SDD to boot from USB, does it matter if I just leave the laptop's SATA cable detached when I disconnect it from the SDD?  I don't think it matters, but I can't find anything definitively about that.  Thanks again!

Comment: The SATA cable doesn't have to be detached when booting from USB.  If nothing's attached to it, there won't be anything "going through it."

Comment: So, just tried to boot from the USB, and no dice. All I got was a solid gray screen when I started it up, regardless of what key combination I tried (I saw some articles that said to hold command and others said to hold option to choose boot drive, and I also just tried cmd+R and cmd+option+R just for good measure). Any additional thoughts with that info?

Comment: Ok, spoke too soon. Right after I posted the last update, the user login screen appeared. I tried to login to my profile, and after it appeared that the password was accepted, it went to the gray screen with a prohibitory symbol. Got any suggestions for what’s next?

Comment: Sorry for the rapid-fire updates. I just realized that I still have my old HDD that I replaced with the SSD, so I tried booting from it via USB, and it worked. I’m logged in and see everything that was there when I migrated from the HDD to the SSD a few years ago. Does this confirm the SSD is fried or should I plug it in via the internal SATA cable just to be certain? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Key combos have nothing to do with fixing a device that's having difficulty booting.  It can put you in a diagnostic mode like Diagnostics or Verbose (see the messages) or it will allow you to select a different boot manager.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've confirmed nothing because your SSD was an unknown quantity to begin with. The idea behind booting off of USB is to **remove** the SATA controller and cable from the equation.  If the problem still existed and if you used the same internal SDD but connected to USB, then it could be drive itself or the whole system.  **Your next step is to boot from a known good drive** like your old HDD or a clean install on a flash disk or another SSD/HDD.  Slow down and take it methodically - rapid fire tests (like comments) confuse things.

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood that I should have been attempting to remove both the controller and the cable. However, I still managed to boot from a known good drive (my old HDD) via USB, and it worked. That's why I thought it might point to a failed SSD and not the SATA cable.